# associated_users does not have a root level key

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

in order to uniquely identify a `associated_users` on must traverse the object graph into the `onsite` object and construct an artificial key.

it makes more sense to either flatten the structure or, more appropriately in my opinion, simply use a site key instead of duplicating data that, if desired, can be pulled from the `/sites` route.

this is an example of where a decent site key would come in handy, but if, as insisted, a mixed case string with, currently, spaces and who knows what else in the future, is what we have for a key then please surface that on the result.

the current structure is unnatural and the nested object graph complicates consumption unnecessarily.

Current:

```
{
  "associated_users": [
    {
      "user_id": 242897,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 9272,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Stack Overflow",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/so/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.stackoverflow.com",
        "site_url": "http://stackoverflow.com",
        "description": "Q&A for programmers",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/so/apple-touch-icon.png"
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 38306,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 111,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Server Fault",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/sf/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.serverfault.com",
        "site_url": "http://serverfault.com",
        "description": "Q&A for system administrators and IT professionals",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/sf/apple-touch-icon.png"
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 31747,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 100,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Super User",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/su/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.superuser.com",
        "site_url": "http://superuser.com",
        "description": "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/su/apple-touch-icon.png"
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 144906,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 1252,
      "on_site": {
        "name": "Stack Overflow Meta",
        "logo_url": "http://sstatic.net/mso/img/logo.png",
        "api_endpoint": "http://api.meta.stackoverflow.com",
        "site_url": "http://meta.stackoverflow.com",
        "description": "Q&A about Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User",
        "icon_url": "http://sstatic.net/mso/apple-touch-icon.png"
      },
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    // stackapss  missing
    {
      "user_id": 14,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 3123,
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    }
  ]
}
```

Proposed: (i would be happy to meet you half way and tolerate the nested `on_site` node if only we can get the site id on the root as shown)

```
{
  "associated_users": [
    {
      "user_id": 242897,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 9272,
      "site_name": "Stack Overflow",
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 38306,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 111,
      "site_name": "Server Fault",
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 31747,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 100,
      "site_name": "Super User",
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 144906,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 1252,
      "site_name": "Stack Overflow Meta",
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    },
    {
      "user_id": 14,
      "user_type": "registered",
      "display_name": "code poet",
      "reputation": 3123,
      "email_hash": "df4a7fbd8a054fd6193ca0ee62952f1f"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're de-serializing `on_site`, just define an equality operator - however that is done on your platform of choice - and be done with it.

Bam, unique key.

---

We're returning the site data to save a query.

Consider, it will probably be a very common use case for `/users/{id}/associated` will be:

- query associated accounts given 1 site/id pair
- get some subset of user activity across all sites the user is active on

If we didn't return the full site data, you'd either have to make a `/sites` call (wasted query, and extra wait time for the user) or implement a caching scheme<sup>*</sup>.  Since we already heavily cache the sites data, it costs us nothing to return the relevant bits of it.

<sub>*Not that there's anything wrong with caching, but if you **have** to implement it for a trivial use case something's a bit dicey.</sub>

Comment: as i said, i can see how the nested site structure could be an illustration of acceptable denormalization. But what you seem reluctant to acknowledge in this and other cases is that your denormalization does not simplify the task of consuming the data. You keep suggesting that we should make efforts to manipulate the data and the structures we create to arrive at what would be seen as a usable result when the inclusion of one simple field of data, that you already have in hand, in the root of the structure in question would allow direct deserialization into a usable object.

Comment: I don't want to have to construct artificial structures and hook the deserialization process with extra measures. I want the data being returned from the api be shaped in a way that is usable as-is. And if that can be done with the inclusion of a field here or there, why not do it? It is not like I am suggesting some outrageous smelly kludge, I am begging for a simple small degree of normalization.

Comment: @code poet - You're keying data, it isn't a horrible kludge to have to construct the keys yourself.  Asking for 100% duplicated data in a return to simply your - and, probably, only your - code is a bit much.  Just reach into the `on_site` object if you have to.  I still think defining an equality operator is the most elegant solution.